# Linking 3 queries together

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I've been working on this all day, and I think my brain isn't functioning correctly right now.

I have 3 tables all "linked" together:
Boards table has:
 - board_id
 - board_name

Topic table has:
 - topic_id
 - topic_board_link (links to a board_id)

Post table has:
 - post_time
 - post_parent (links to a topic)

Essentially, I would like it to display the board, the last topic in the selected board, and the last post in that thread.   So far, with my half functioning brain, I have (doesn't work, since max_topic isn't defined at the end, and it only returns 1 row):

```
SELECT 
    b.board_name,
    MAX(t.topic_id) as max_topic,
    MAX(p.post_id) as max_post
FROM board_list b
    INNER JOIN (topic_list t, post_list p)
    ON t.topic_board_link=b.board_id AND p.post_id=max_topic
```

Is there a way that I can do this without using tons of subqueries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `last_topic_id` to the `boards` table and `last_post_id` to the `topics` table.

In this case you will have simple and really fast query that will return all what you want.

Comment: I thought about that, but topics & posts tend to get deleted rather quickly, and I have a feeling something will inevitably mess up in the long run.

Comment: @kevin: deleting and maintaining this reference is **MUCH CHEAPER** task, than selecting with subqueries. You can maintain them automatically with triggers.

Comment: Meh, okay. I will do that then. What exactly do you mean by triggers?

Comment: @kevin: I meant http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html. In few words triggers it is a special stored objects that can be called (triggered) automatically after some event. IE: row added, row deleted, etc. With triggers you can write procedures once and newer take care of making references (maintaining referential integrity) manually in your business logic in programming language.